# How to set up typescript 0.9.5 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to write a game in Typescript but I am having a hard time setting things up.
I am using visual studio 2012 and I installed typescript 0.9.5.

What I want is to build an app/game like I would in C# or AS3, meaning using putting classes in seperate files and using modules to seperate/connect code. This would then compile to either a single file or some kind of require.js like solution (which I'm also not clear about).

But I have done a lot of research and ran in to a lot of hurdles.

-There are a lot of references to calling something like "tsc greeter.ts" but when I use this in the visual studio command window I get back "Command "tsc" is not valid." I tried adding the tsc folder to environment variables path, but this didn't change anything. So I can't really run it. Also I don't understand how tsc would know where greeter.ts is located.

-I'm confused between the "///" and the import statement. How do these factor in the structuring of an app?

-It seems there are a lot of ways to make a typescript app, which all have different requirements and code style and structure. Is there no standard way, or am I just mistaken and is there a good way to approach this?

So the main question is: How do I build a typescript app/game structured like a c# or AS3 app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer just some of your question, you no longer need the /// reference like this:
`/// <reference path="../typings/jquery.d.ts"/>`  This was used in earlier versions of typescript, however now it will find any typescript files in your project for you.

I don't think there is a 'standard' way to create a typescript project any more than there is C#, there are many design patterns and you will have to research the pros and cons of both and choose one.

You should also no longer need to run "tsc greeter.ts" to compile your code. It will compile on build of the project.